How to capture replies to a bot's message in a Microsoft Teams Channel without mentioning the bot?
I have developed a message extension bot app for Microsoft Teams and I want to capture replies to a message posted by the bot in a Teams channel without requiring users to mention the bot directly.
I am using Node.js and TypeScript for my bot.
The bot is registered in the Azure Bot Service.
I want to capture replies to this message without users needing to mention the bot. How can I achieve this?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

A user can mention someone or reply to a message. The replies relationship lists replies for a specified message, but doesn't include mentions. Can you [edit] the question to clarify the objective?
